# Moreh Makom or Mar'eh Makom

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, words, acronyms

A Torah source is often referred to as a M"M, which I have heard read as both מורה מקום, Moreh Makom and מראה מקום, Mar'eh Makom, (see [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=dKtFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA266&lpg=PA266&dq=%22%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D%22%20%22%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D%22&source=bl&ots=uDYnx6-YMG&sig=ACfU3U1f9e5MtZRyzdL5OMVVTAf9S9j6xA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie8pn1n43gAhVjxoMKHRljANwQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D%22%20%22%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D%22&f=false) for example) which have similar meanings, and mean something like "placefinder".

On the one hand, the Talmud uses Mar'eh Makom in a number of places to refer to a placeholder (e.g. Bava Basra 76b, Kiddushin 48b).  On the other hand, in the introduction to the Beis Yosef, Rav Yosef Kar'o uses the word Moreh Makom to  mean finding a source for a Halacha.

Which is technically more correct/older when **referring to a Torah source**, and are there any articles that discuss this and conclude one way or the other?

Comment: I’ve always heard the term as מראה מקומות, not מורה.

Comment: Technically, you can't say מורה מקום in proper Hebrew, as מורה means הוראה and you can't להורות מקום. It's just a common misspelling. The right one is of course מראה מקום.

Comment: Where did you see the use of מורה מקום?

Comment: @alberko I don't remember which people say it, but I have definitely read it. But didn't you read the post, which gives an example from the Beis Yosef?

Comment: @AlBerko Why is it any worse to say that one “teaches the place” rather than “shows the place”?

Comment: @DonielF Then it should read מורה על מקום. You can say מורה דרך because a way can be studied but a place can't be studied.